# How to reinstall google play store app in jellybean?

Tags: google-play-store, 4.1-jelly-bean

I have telus samsung galaxy s2x with android jellybean 4.1.2 (non rooted).

When going on play store I got an error about authentication needed. So I did uninstall updates from application manager (as described in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/20391/16575)). Now the play store app got replaced with `com.android.vending`, which is like the old "market" app.

That app seems to crash frequently. How can I restore the new play store app again?

Comment: First, "authentication needed" means you've got to enter your credentials (so I don't know what made you uninstall updates). Second, the playstore app usually auto-updates itself; but in a state where "authentication needed" is asked by it, I'm not sure whether this auto-update still works. If it does, it usually takes between some minutes and a few days. So how long ago did you uninstall updates? And does this error message for authentication still appear?

Comment: I got the idea from the selected answer here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20369/getting-authentication-is-required-when-trying-to-access-the-play-store

Comment: Ah, OK – thanks! I've integrated that hint with your question. And I see you've found your answer, good news :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Android Police** has all the apks. [Here's](http://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23487008491963661) the lastest one.

Comment: reinstalling the app fixed it.